# Find line of xaml file that is causing System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Getting a System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException when trying to run a Xamarin forms app.  The problem lies in the format of the Xaml code, but I am not sure which line is broken.

Is there a way to get Xamarin Studio to highlight which line contains broken/invalid xml?

Comment: You can process the XAML at compile time, which may help: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying the xaml into an online xml formatter (e.g. http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-formatter.html) and that identified the issue immediately.  Will use this method going forward until equivalent functionality is included within Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But if you could share your xaml file, we might be able to find what line is wrong, why, and report better error in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers already give, I usually go to the problem page and start commenting out XAML code until the error stops. Then slowly uncomment until you can at least narrow it down to a specific section, layout, or even element.